# How can I add the filter so that API call is returning just the results that I want?

Tags: php, filter, akeneo

This is what I got so far, but it doesn't work.

```
public function getCompleteness(){
    $searchBuilder = new AkeneoSearchBuilder();
    $searchBuilder->addFilter('completeness', '=', 100);

    try {
        $products = $this->apiClient->getProductApi()->all(
            50,
            [
                'search' => $searchBuilder->getFilters(),
                'scope' => 'ecommerce'
            ]
        );
    } catch (HttpException $e){
        echo "Message: " . $e->getMessage();
        echo "Code: " . $e->getCode();
    }

    return $products;
}
```

}

This is the call that I am trying to use from Akeneo API.

```
{{url}}/api/rest/v1/products?search={"completeness":[{"operator":"=","value":100,"scope":"ecommerce"}]}
```

How can I use GetCompleteness() method in order that it produces some results ? I have problem with using AkeneoSearchBuilder();

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What doesn't work? Do you have any error message? Did you follow the readme file of the official Akeneo php client https://github.com/akeneo/api-php-client/blob/master/README.md ?

Comment: Thanks grena for the response. Hmmm, yes.. But I got an error that the scope is not correct.

Comment: This is first time I am using AkeneoSearchBuilder, so it could happen that I have made something wrong in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
$searchBuilder = new AkeneoSearchBuilder();
$searchBuilder->addFilter('completeness', '=', 100);
$products = $this->apiClient->getProductApi()->all(
    50,
    [
        'search' => $searchBuilder->getFilters(),
        'scope' => 'ecommerce'
    ]
);
```

It basically means: "*For all products complete on scope "undefined", give me all their "ecommerce" values*".

What you are trying to achieve is (I guess): "*For all products complete on scope "ecommerce", give me all their values*".

As you can read on the official documentation about [completeness filter](https://api.akeneo.com/documentation/filter.html#on-completeness), you need to specify a scope:

```
$searchBuilder = new AkeneoSearchBuilder();
$searchBuilder->addFilter('completeness', '=', 100, ['scope' => 'ecommerce']);
```

Now you can retrieve their values, by calling:

```
$products = $this->apiClient->getProductApi()->all(
    50,
    [
        'search' => $searchBuilder->getFilters()
    ]
);
```

Note that I removed the "scope" parameter here.

**To resume:**

- You need to [specify a scope](https://api.akeneo.com/documentation/filter.html#on-completeness) when filtering by completeness
- The [scope parameter on the query](https://api.akeneo.com/api-reference-21.html#get_products) is to retrieve only values of this scope